# Regular expression c# on file upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to perform a regular expression checking for upload control file name and extension, the format is [UTMC][XX][YYYY][MM].txt. XX represent any 2 alphabets, YYYY represents year and MM represents month

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: So far Im only managed to validate the extensions ValidationExpression="([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.txt|)$", the specific format of file name is too confusing for me.

Comment: What does `UTMC` mean?

Comment: It is just a header for the filename, the file has to start with the name UTMC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check for the full filename string, the following regex pattern string might work

```
var pattern = @"^UTMC[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}\.txt$";
```

Details:

- `^`: start of string / start of line
- `UTMC`: static text to be expected
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` represents two letters (the [XX]), assuming you mean the a-zA-Z range when you say "alphabets"
- `[0-9]{6}` represents a sequence of 6 digits. If you need to validate their content to be actually year and month instead of arbitrary numbers, you have to define more fine grained logic
- `\.txt` static text at the end of filename
- `$` end of string / end of line

Comment: Thank you, with the explanation, i can now more understand and try to create more other regex pattern. Very much appreciated.